# It is correcto to instantiate val in scala trait?

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

I'm working in a spray, akka, scala, reactivemongo project and I have this trait

```
trait PersistenceManager {

  val driver = new MongoDriver
  val connection = driver.connection(List("localhost"))

  def loan[A](collectionName: String)(f: BSONCollection => Future[A]): Future[A] = {
    val db = connection("flujo_caja_db")
    val collection = db.collection(collectionName)
    f(collection)
  }
}
```

Also I have Dao's objects to use that trait like so:

```
object Dao extends PersistenceManager {

   def find = loan("users"){
     collection =>
          collection.find(BsonDocument())....
   }

}
```

It is correct to instanciate those database vals in my persistencemanager trait?
It works really good.

Thank you!

Comment: Are you okay with the fact that a driver and connection instance will be instantiated for every object and every class instance that you mix this trait into?

Comment: That was exactly the thing I was thinking.. I finnally managed to use a singleton object. Thank you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm thinking you want things defined like this, to prevent multiple `MongoDriver` and connection pools from being created:

```
object PersistenceManager{
  val driver = new MongoDriver
  val connection = driver.connection(List("localhost"))
}


trait PersistenceManager {
  import PersistenceManager._

  def loan[A](collectionName: String)(f: BSONCollection => Future[A]): Future[A] = {
    val db = connection("flujo_caja_db")
    val collection = db.collection(collectionName)
    f(collection)
  }
}
```